# Primes and Quadratics

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$,$b$ $\in$ $\Bbb N$  such that the equations
$$x^2+ax+b$$
$$x^2+bx+a$$
have all of their roots as integers. Find all $a$ and $b$.

**My Approach**
I tried using Vieta's Relations but the process got too much complicated and I gave up.
Any help?

Comment: But the $x$ terms are given positive here.

Comment: Yes, but with  $-x$, your equations become exactly $x^2-ax+b=0$ and $x^2-bx+a$, as in the duplicate. In any case, it works the same way.